# Independent conditional formatting based on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have created an inventory management document for a warehouse. It has a worksheet called "IN" and a worksheet called "formulas". In the "formulas" sheet, I have created complex (well... relatively complex anyway) formula that calculates the point at which my inventory stock is so low that I need to place an order (re-supply point).

On the "IN" worksheet I display how much I have in stock (of any given item). Right now there is no other way to tell if what I have "IN" storage is enough (in relation to the re-order point) unless I go into the "formulas" page.

What I want to do is the following:

I want to change the background color of every single cell between A4 and A1000 (independently) to red, based on whether D4 to D1000 (Independently) is less than or equal to their counterparts (which are 37 cells apart) in "Formulas" N10 to N36862.

Example:
Inventory name (A4) is its regular color because the amount in stock (D4) is more than the re-supply point indicated on the Formulas worksheet (cell N10)

In other words:
A4 (regular color) because D4 > "formulas!N10"

At the same time
A5 (red) because D5 <= "formulas!N47"

At the same time
A6 (regular color) because D6 > "formulas!N84"

etc.

The reason I need VBA to do this is because the re-supply points on the "Formulas" worksheet are (as you can see in the example) 37 cells apart, and because there are 1000 lines and doing this manually through the Conditional Formatting menu would take several days (and I don't have the time at work to spend doing that).

I intend to write a code in VBA for the first inventory line (A4) and then copy it for every inventory line, using Excel to change the values of the lines (I know how - done it before, its a tricky but doable). By all means let me know if anyone has a better idea :)

I have tried more than 20 different methods based on what I have found on the web so far, but I have yet to crack this code. I still haven't found anyone trying to do exactly the same thing as this and so interpreting the different methods to suit my needs has proved extremely difficult.

Comment: Why not add a column on your "formulas" tab which pulls up the ColN values and performs the necessary calculation? Then your conditional formatting is straightforward.

Comment: Hello Tim, and thank you for taking the time. The reason I haven't done this is because I would still have to refer to 1000cells individually to make the column you describe. In addition, I already have a lot of information on the "Formulas" page and I don't want to add more if it can be avoided. I want to make the document as easy to comprehend as possible (withouth the user having to know much about excel to interprit it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still do it using conditional formatting, I think.
You need to add a conditional format that applies to A4:A1000 and set it up to 'format cells where this formula is true' (that's conditional formatting > new rule > use a formula).
The Formula will be this;

```
=$D4<=INDEX(formulas!N:N, ROW($D4)*37-138)
```

Obviously then you just need to set the colour/formatting to highlight relevant cells in.

Comment: Quick Explanation; the `INDEX()` function returns the value of a cell by inputting a range in which to look, then the row and column values as separate coordinates - in this case you tell it to look in column N of Formulas sheet, and the other part of the formula calculates which row the corresponding value will be found on.

Comment: Thank you Spencer, I appreciate the effort. Unfortunately this did not work. I input the formula exactly but got an error reply. Having said that, where does the *37-138 come from?

Comment: Ahh, apologies - what was the error? The `*37-138` was intended to return the correct row for each corresponding value (`*` meaning multiply, and 4 x37-138=10, 5 x37-138=47, 6 x37-138=84, etc) if that makes sense?

Comment: Perhaps try inputting the formula without the `=` at the start?

Comment: also if the sheet name is at all wrong, for instance having a capital letter at the start, that would make a difference.

Comment: .... In Norwegian we have en expression... "Jeg bøyer meg i støvet". Literally translated it means "I bow before the dust"... the actual meaning is that I am so humbled by the awesomeness of something that I bow before it... THANK YOU for your help. Honestly I've asked the same question on a different forum and I got the same answer there... I would NEVER have figured this one out on my own without some serious Excel courses first. THANK YOU!!!!! YOU ARE THE EXCEL JEDI MASTER!

Comment: @John123456789 Thank you, although really I'm still a beginner in most areas of excel, just happen to know some handy tricks here and there. Please could you click the tick to mark this as the answer to the question, if it works?